# Truncate Hive "managed table" over JDBC in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have been trying to truncate a table located in a Redshift cluster using the a managed table of Hive but unsuccessfully so far.

```
CREATE TABLE SPARK_DB.TEST
USING com.databricks.spark.redshift
    OPTIONS (
    dbtable 'reshift_db.test',
    url 'jdbc:redshift://endpoint:5439/db?ssl=true&user=usr&password=pwd',
    tempdir 's3n://mybucket',
    forward_spark_s3_credentials 'true',
    tempformat 'CSV GZIP')
```

but this would run "successfully" (= no error) but have no effect on the underlying data:
TRUNCATE TABLE SPARKDB.TEST;

Then I tried playing with the TBLPROPERTIES of the managed table, but nothing worked:

```
TBLPROPERTIES ("auto.purge"="true")
TBLPROPERTIES ("external"="true")
TBLPROPERTIES ("external.table.purge"="true")
TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true")
```

How do make spark push down this "truncate table" to redshift and why is it not doing right now?

Comment: I haven't worked on RedShift, but is it required to specify the file location (tempdir) when creating Managed table ? Generally in Hive managed table locations are determined by Hive itself.

Comment: I am not sure it is but it is sort of mandatory if you want to copy data in/out reshift: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift